# How to join SQL column elements together?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, select, element

I have an SQL table with the column named expenses like this

[image]

I want to write a query to return all the elements of this column separated by a comma. For the above example output should be:-

```
hotel,taxi,food,movie
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I am using SQLite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [group_concat](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat) aggregate function:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(expenses)
FROM   my_table
```